# Typeorm 0.3.5 filter by enum column not equal. type error

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have this setup:

```js
export enum TestEnum {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
}

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({enum: TestEnum})
    test: TestEnum
}
```

I'm trying to query users like this: `test != 'A'`
But i keep getting a type error.

Here is what I tried:

```js
const users = await AppDataSource.manager.find(User, {
        where: {
            test: Not(TestEnum.A)
        }
    })
```

The error message:

```
Type 'FindOperator<TestEnum>' is not assignable to type 'TestEnum | FindOperator<TestEnum.A> | FindOperator<TestEnum.B> | FindOperator<TestEnum.C>'.
  Type 'FindOperator<TestEnum>' is not assignable to type 'FindOperator<TestEnum.A>'.
    Type 'TestEnum' is not assignable to type 'TestEnum.A'.ts(2322)
```

```js
test: Not(Equal(TestEnum.A))
```

Gives the same error

If I remove the `Not` it works fine.

Comment: Was able to find a workaround: ```Not<TestEnum.A)>(TestEnum.A)```. but this seem kind of hacky

Comment: i guess is also available doing: `Not(TestEnum.A.toString())`

Comment: yeah, seems kinda hacky too, thanks for the suggestion tho

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest release (0.3.12) fixed this issue for me.

There are still a couple open issues on the typeorm repo mentioning this ([issue 1](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9745), [issue 2](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9002)), but it looks like they got resolved by [this PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9607).